# Novato no waze. De que forma posso inserir no meu site?

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

Tenho um site e necessito inserir um mapa do api do waze. Como faco?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo**

```
<?php
//exibir o Mapa

?>




<style>
    .exibirpainel{
            margin-top: 0px;
            height: 400px;
            width: 700px;
            background-color: blue;
    }
</style>







<div id="exibirpainel" class="exibirpainel">




</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse problema inserindo um iframe no meu sistema PHP

```
<div id="exibirMapa" class="exibirMapa">

<iframe src="https://embed.waze.com/iframe?zoom=12&lat=32.10911&lon=34.81773" width="700" height="500"></iframe>

</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problema resolvido.
Link para documentação do [waze](https://support.google.com/waze/partners/answer/6287370?hl=pt-BR)